# update query using SQLQuery in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have to do this:
Suppose:

```
int posterid=100;
int userid=5;

SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery("update poster set userid='"+userid+"' where posterid='"+posterid+"' ");
query.executeUpdate();
```

It is not working, If I write:

```
SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery("update poster set userid=:userid where posterid=:posterid ");
query.setParameter("userid",userid);
query.setParameter("posterid",posterid);

query.executeUpdate();
```

Is is not working too.

Comment: can u post what kind of error or exception u r getting ,with this limited info i dont think anyone will be able to help u

Comment: rather u should go through this http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting any question

Comment: paste some error message more.

Comment: It is not throwing any exception, when I print query.executeUpdate() method, it returns 0, even though I have commited the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**session.beginTransaction();**

SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery("update poster set userid='"+userid+"' where posterid='"+posterid+"' "); 

query.executeUpdate();

**session.getTransaction().commit();**

Answer (score 0):

How do you retrieve the session object ?
You must ensure that your update query run inside a transaction that has not be flagged as read-only.

You have different way to do this, depending of your execution context.

Try NobodyElse method or add `@Transactional` annotation to your method

Answer (score -1):

I have rectified the issue. Now it is working fine.

There was the problem of committing transaction.